# Which one to use JSON XML or database cannot decide

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, database, json

I am developing an app which sends an id and in return the php sends a json node to the client. My question should i save my data as a static php array as shown in the bottom code or save the data to an external xml/json file or should I use a database? I might have up to 10,000 items in the array. Please suggest.

```
<?php
    // Fill up array with names
    $a = array(
                array("id"=>1001, "name"=>"One", "address"=>"", "city"=>"", "state"=>""),
            array("id"=>1002, "name"=>"Two", "address"=>"", "city"=>"", "state"=>""),
            array("id"=>1003, "name"=>"Three", "address"=>"", "city"=>"", "state"=>""),
            array("id"=>1004, "name"=>"Four", "address"=>"", "city"=>"", "state"=>""),
            array("id"=>1005, "name"=>"Five", "address"=>"", "city"=>"", "state"=>""),
            array("id"=>1006, "name"=>"Six", "address"=>"", "city"=>"", "state"=>"")
            );

    //get the q parameter from URL
    $q=$_GET["q"];
    //lookup all hints from array if length of q>0
    if (strlen($q) > 0)
    {
        $hint="";
        $att = "id";
        for($i=0; $i<count($a); $i++)
        {    
           if($q==$a[$i][$att])
           {
              echo json_encode($a[$i]);
           }       
        }
    }
    echo "";
    ?>
```

Comment: A database would be preferred in your case. Also, to make your faster (if the IDs are unique) .. have `die(json_encode(...));`

Answer (score 0):

I definitely recommend using a Database. Maybe at the beginning you think is easier to access the JSON element through a file but if you have hundreds of records, it could be hard to handle, especially if you are searching through the data. If you feel comfortable using JSON maybe you could try [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) for working with something like a JSON-DB environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to have that many records, you should definitely use a database. I would recommend checking out SQLite, it's a very simple and compact database. Not sure if you meant app for a smartphone, but if you did then SQLite is available on iOS and Android. It's compatible with everything from smartphones to web servers to desktops - it's a good DB to know. A lot of good documentation on it too. It's sponsored by Mozilla, Adobe, and Oracle. http://www.sqlite.org/

Answer (score 0):

A database is probably the easiest solution with an acceptable performance.

If you expect to deal with more than around 10000 requests per second a traditional database is probably too slow, a process that keep the data in memory would be faster. PHP is notoriously bad for this, in fact it is bad for most things but running a normal website. The stateless nature can make debugging easier, but if your application mostly deals with things that are inherently stateful it is just a pain to deal with. Ask yourself if PHP is the right tool for the job, Node.js for instance would make storing the list in memory an intuitive and easy solution.

In general, no matter what storage solution you choose it would seem most natural to store the data as the JSON string format you intend to serve, unless the data it is based on change very often.

Your current code has two major flaws:

- It loads the entire list for every single request as the PHP process is started because the list is in code. This wouldn't be much of an issue in most other languages as you normally don't start a new process very often. (You generally shouldn't put big amounts of data in your code anyway, but that is because it tend to grow hard to maintain.)
- You loop through the entire list to find the requested item, use the `id` as a key and you can fetch the correct record in virtually no time, like this:

.

```
$a = array(
    "1001"=>array("id"=>1001, "name"=>"One", "address"=>"", "city"=>"", "state"=>"")
)

//Get the requested record
$a[$q];
```

Comment: Actually this data is a local business list lists. So it will not change very often. May be will add or delete 2/3 items from the list each. That is what I expect business do not open and close every day. I am not expecting to get 10000 request per second but expecting the local business to list around 10000. I thought instead of passing the search request to sql server it will be better to save it as php string array. But looks like every one is suggesting to use database!